# Remove placeholder after type (and not after focus)

Tags: jquery, css, input, placeholder

I am using a jQuery placeholder plugin from Daniel Stocks.

This is the plugin:
https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js

It works actually fine for all the fields except the following little problem:
In Chrome when the focus is on the field, the placeholder stays until you type something. But in IE and FF the placeholder text is removed after focus.
I would them all like to behave like in Chrome.

The thing is in chrome the placeholder is natively supported, so even without the plugin it works the  way I woulg like it to. In FF it works too without the plugin except with the earlier mentioned problem. And in IE it doens't work without the plugin, as you might have guessed.

Comment: But what problem are you trying to solve? The users of these browsers with native support, regardless of whether they are, or act like, Webkit, are used to the way they behave. Why change the UI?

Comment: simply the problem that on focus the placeholder is deleted. So when the user clicks on tab to move to the next field and doesn't see beforehand what the placeholder was he has to go back and forth.

Comment: Not only that, but combining placeholders with autofocus is a non-starter with FF and IE. When a page is loaded with an autofocused field, it should **not** remove the placeholder. Chrome does this correctly. FF and IE trip up. A perfect example of where you would want to use this is a login form. Or even any "create" page where you want the user to begin immediately typing, but have a textbox hint.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the plugin. If you really want to disable the native support for Chrome you can edit line 71 in the code:

```
var NATIVE_SUPPORT = !!("placeholder" in document.createElement( "input" ));
```

to:

```
var NATIVE_SUPPORT = false
```

By doing this, you'll simply make ALL browsers use the plugin, even those with native support.

I'd like to point out that this is not only a "Chrome" defined behavior. Safari (and mobile safari on iOS) behaves this way. These users are most likely "used" to this behavior, so maybe ask the question, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would upvote you so many times were I able, for solving the problem so efficiently and again for the question at the end.

Comment: While I certainly understand that the user is used to a way the browser operates, I think in this specific case it wouldn't be really annoying to them. The thing I want to achieve is that users can see the placeholder at all times before entering text into a field so they don't have to go back and forth between field when they didn't notice the right placeholder. In my opinion that is quite user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following section in the source from line 77:

```
input.focus(function() {
    placeholder.hide();
});
```

with this:

```
input.keyup(function() {
    if (input.val() != "") {
        placeholder.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't override the settings in Firefox and in IE the placeholder is added to the actual input value, so it doesn't dissapear.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realise you were looking to amend their base functionality. That may not be technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had a need for something similar and made some mods to the jquery ui placeholder plugin you mentioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/sigmabetatooth/5j55m/

feel free to bump up against it and share your thoughts.

you will also not on clearing of the field via backspace or other means the placeholder returns and on selection of the input when placeholder is present the cursor will be placed at the beginning of the text.

@Daniel if you are interested in me pushing it to you just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can make placeholder work in IE with

//Setting Placeholder in IE

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){        
    var input = $(this);                
    $(input).val(input.attr('placeholder'));                
    $(input).focus(function(){
         if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
         }
    });     
    $(input).blur(function(){
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    });
});
```